# Why would VS Code have a problem with my fields being private?

Tags: java, field, abstract-class, private, protected

I started off by making the fields private but VS Code didn't like that so I switched it to protected. I'm used to coding in C/C++ so I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing...

Anyone know why I wouldn't be able to make my fields private?

```
public abstract class Employee 
{
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected int id;

    public Employee()
    {
        this.firstName="Plony";
        this.lastName="Almoni";
        this.id=0;
    }

    public Employee(String FN, String LN, int ID)
    {
        this.firstName=FN;
        this.lastName=LN;
        this.id=ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "VSC didnt like that" mean? What did it say? The code is valid with the fields being `private`. We need details of what exactly your VSC is saying. That said, voting to close your question because it is lacking details (see [ask]).

Comment: "VS Code didn't like that" - are we supposed to guess an error message? I suspect it was only a warning that the fields were not being used, but who knows.

Comment: Error message: The value of the field HourlyEmployee.hours is not usedJava(570425421)

Comment: That message is a warning, not an error. It means that the field is assigned but you're not using it inside the class, so probably you want to remove it. This is great when you're refactoring code and there are unused fields that need to be deleted. For new classes, you can ignore them while defining the fields, unless you won't use them...

Comment: wouldn't the fact that the constructor assigns a value to them cause them to be considered "used fields"?

Comment: They're assigned, but not used. Using a field is, for example `return this.id` because the value of the field is being read.